# TEI-P5: how to add a css classname to html table tag?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tei

I'd like to style a specific class of tables differently in transformed HTML via CSS.

For example in XML:

```
<table>
  <row role="label">
    <cell>
      Manuscrit Bodmer
    </cell>
    <cell>
      Manuscrit fr. 1457
    </cell>
  </row>
  <row>
    <cell>
      <lb/>Début <supplied><locus from="1r">fol. 1</locus></supplied> :
    </cell>
    <cell>
      <note><lb/><supplied>fol. 6v&#7506;, ligne 15</supplied> :</note>
    </cell>
  </row>
</table>
```

In XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:table[not(. = '')]">
    <xsl:param name="sprache"/>
    <xsl:element name="table">
        <xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-param name="sprache" select="$sprache"/></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

To achieve that I'm thinking of applying a specific CSS class to that table eg. in generated HTML

```
<table class="comparison-table">
```

and style it in css.
Is this possible? And how can I achieve that exactly?

--- Update
Thanks to @zx485 I updated XML & XSL to:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:table[@rend='comparison-table']">
    <xsl:param name="sprache"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>comparison-table</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-param name="sprache" select="$sprache"/></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:table[not(. = '')]">
    <xsl:param name="sprache"/>
    <xsl:element name="table">
        <xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-param name="sprache" select="$sprache"/></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

And in my XML:

```
<table rend="comparison-table">
    <row role="label">
        <cell>
            Manuscrit Bodmer
        </cell>
        <cell>
            Manuscrit fr. 1457
        </cell>
    </row>
  ....
```

But in the generated HTML file the tables don't have css classname "comparison-table".

=== Update 2: As @zx485 suggested in the discussion room I just had to change  to

```
<xsl:template match="tei:table">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your template to

```
<xsl:template match="tei:table[not(. = '')]">
    <xsl:param name="sprache"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>comparison-table</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-param name="sprache" select="$sprache"/></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Is there a way to restrict the css-classname to only those tables with a identifier named "comparison-table"? Right now with your modification all html-tables get the classname "comparison-table".

Comment: I used your given template. So simply creating templates matching your criteria for these specific `table`s will suffice (use predicates like `match="table[predicate]"`.

Comment: Ah, ok. How do I have to write the identifier in XML eg. <table xxx="comparison-table"> ?

Comment: Just like in the answer: `xsl:copy` copies the `table` element and `<xsl:attribute name="class">...` creates its attribute.

Comment: for a better overview of my current xml/xsl i updated the post.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The template I gave you above sets a `class` attribute on some `table` elements.

Comment: I want to be able to define which table in XML should be styled specially with css. If in XML only <table> tag is used, then <xsl:template match="tei:table[not(. = '')]"> should be executed. If in XML <table rend="comparison-table"> (is this even allowed?) then <xsl:template match="tei:table[@rend='comparison-table']"> should be executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154429/discussion-between-zx485-and-standardnerd).

Answer (score 0):

I refactored zx485's solution with xsl:if, it's probably more readable and follows the DRY-principle:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:table">
  <xsl:param name="sprache"/>
  <xsl:element name="table">
    <xsl:if test="@rend='comparison-table'">
      <xsl:attribute
name="class"><xsl:text>comparison-table</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates><xsl:with-param name="sprache"
select="$sprache"/></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```